# How to link dylib with specific directory

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, clang, dylib

```
>>> gcc -o main main.c -L/Foo/Bar -lBaz
>>> otool -L main
main:
    /usr/local/lib/libBaz.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.0.0)
```

Because it uses `/usr/local/lib/libBaz.dylib` but not `/Foo/Bar/libBaz.dylib`.

How can I link the correct path?